# Using sans font for tick labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, unicode-math, sans-serif

I am using a sans font for my figures. Hence I also want the tick labels of the pgfplots to be in sans. The tick labels, however, are set in a math enviroment. So changing the text font does not change anythings here. I have seen a [possible solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185930/pgfplots-using-sans-serif-fonts-for-numbers-and-text-not-variables-in-figures) here on tex.SE. The problem is that get many error messages like that:

```
! LaTeX Error: Symbol font `um_fam1' not defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.23        \end{axis}
```

I think the problem is that a non-math font is used with `unicode-math`, which is not the intended use case for `unicode-math`. I really tried many ways to change the math font to sans, see for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128887/switching-math-fonts-with-unicode-math), but the essence is that a sans math font is not possible.

Since it is not possible to use a sans math font, maybe it is possible to change the pgfplots to use not an mathematical enviroment. I'm asking here, if it is possible to patch `pgfplots` to use an non mathematical enviroment for the tick labels? I understand this enviromnent is needed for fractions or some log scales. But I actually don't use those. So I'm fine with a solution ignoring those cases. The only important characters are digits and commas.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% In reality I do not use Adventor but another sans font
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\SendSettingsToPgf

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=x direction, ylabel=y direction, xmin=-1, xmax=1,domain=-1:1]
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \textsf{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be achieved using a setting in the `tick label style` key. By default (without getting into too much details), `pgf`/`pgfplots` uses some "`\ensuremath`-like" business internally when typesetting the tick labels. We can disable this by setting `tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}`. What this does is tells `pgf` to assume that the input is *already* in math mode (though it is not in this case) and that the "`\ensuremath`-like" function is not required. So the numbers are passed in directly and typeset in the specified `\sffamily`.

### Code

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% In reality I do not use Adventor but another sans font
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\SendSettingsToPgf

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel=x direction,
  ylabel=y direction,
  xmin=-1, xmax=1,
  domain=-1:1,
  tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true} % <=== added here
]
  \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\textsf{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. The only flaw is the wrong minus sign. But I found a solution to fix this, which I will post later.

Comment: thank you, 4h I am trying to convinve the thing to do what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't affect exponential style tick labels (e.g. 10^2).

Comment: @Xaser that's probably a different question, but the exponent ticks (like in log axes or scaled ticks) have different style keys that you can adjust, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402405/21344.

Answer (score 8):

The solution of Paul Gessler works very well. The only flaw is the small minus sign. In fact it is a hypen. I found a way to circumvent this by using `\num` command of the `siunitx` package.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% In reality I do not use Adventor but another sans font
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\SendSettingsToPgf

% The following command will print the tick label with siunitx's \num{}
\def\myprinttick{ %
    \bgroup %
        \pgfmathprintnumberto{\tick}{\retval}%
        \num{\retval}%
    \egroup %
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sisetup{mode=text,text-rm=\sffamily}] % <- changed
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=x direction, ylabel=y direction, xmin=-1, xmax=1, 
        domain=-1:1,
        tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}, % from Paul Gessler
        xticklabel={\myprinttick}, % <- added
        yticklabel={\myprinttick} % <- added
        ]
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \textsf{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
\end{document}
```

[image]