Clickable labels to the left of bars in chart
I would like to alter the bar chart given in section TEST1.
In section TEST2, instead of having simple textual labels, I would like clickable links (with a shortened version of the URL as the text, and the bars sufficiently far to the right).

This is what I have come up with so far:
\documentclass[
11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{biolinum}
\usepackage[final,babel]{microtype}
% \usepackage{minted}
% \setminted[]{frame=single,framesep=1mm,
%   baselinestretch=0.6,fontsize=\small,tabsize=2,breaklines,breakanywhere}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\hypersetup{
  breaklinks,
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={red!80!black},
  citecolor={blue!50!black},
  urlcolor={blue!50!black},
  pdfstartview=FitH
}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{fp}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function shorten_url(url)
    local length = #url
    local maximum = 16
    if length > maximum then
        local shortened = string.sub(url, 1, maximum/2) .. "..." .. string.sub(url, -maximum/2)
        return shortened
    else
        return url
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\shorturl}[1]{%
    \href{https://www.virustotal.com/gui/domain/#1}{\directlua{tex.print(shorten_url("#1"))}}%
}


% #1: Kategorie
% $2: Domain
\newcommand{\barchartdomain}[2]{%
  {\scriptsize\textcolor{black}{\textsc{(#1)}~}}%
  \href{https://www.virustotal.com/gui/domain/#2}{\footnotesize\shorturl{#2}}%
}


\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\section{Blockierte Anfragen}
 
\subsection{TEST1}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    % title  = \textbf{Brauchen wir einen Titel?},
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={\,},
    y=4.5mm,
    xbar,
    xmin=-2,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    yticklabel style  = {font=\scshape},
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = {0.05, lower},
    ytick             = data,
    bar width         = 3mm,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scshape},
%
    % hier absteigend nach Häufigkeit(!) sortieren
    symbolic y coords = {
      maldom,
      malware,
      scam,
    }
    ]
%
    % hier ist die Sortierung egal
    \addplot coordinates {
      (4943,maldom)
      (545,malware)
      (56,scam)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \caption{}
\end{figure}

\subsection{TEST2}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    % title  = \textbf{Brauchen wir einen Titel?},
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={\,},
    y=4.5mm,
    xbar,
    xmin=-2,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    yticklabel style  = {font=\scshape},
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = {0.05, lower},
    ytick             = data,
    bar width         = 3mm,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scshape},
%
    % hier absteigend nach Häufigkeit(!) sortieren
    symbolic y coords = {
      maldom,
      malware,
      scam,
    }
    ]
%
    % hier ist die Sortierung egal
    \addplot coordinates {
      (4943,maldom)
      (56,scam)
      (545,malware)
    };

    % Custom nodes with clickable links
    \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:0,maldom)   {\barchartdomain{maldom}{example.com/maldom}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:0,malware)  {\barchartdomain{malware}{example.com/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/malware}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:0,scam)     {\barchartdomain{scam}{example.com}};
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

but here the labels overprint the bars.
What is the simplest way to achieve a similar layout as in TEST1? I have toyed with reading labels from a table addplot table, but haven't been successful so far.
I have another question: How can I get the numbers at the right end of the bars to appear in the Linux Biolinum font used in the document? The sfmath package does not help; I was led to believe the numbers are in math mode due to their being typeset in Computer Modern.

I'm not sure I understand the question fully - would it suffice to set the coordinates manually, for example at (axis cs:456,scam) for the scam bar? Also: don't use inputenc (utf8 is default since many years) or fontenc (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412757/do-i-need-to-use-usepackaget1fontenc-if-i-use-lualatex).

For the label font see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191246/using-sans-font-for-tick-labels-in-pgfplots, in this case you need nodes near coords style={font=\scshape, /pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},.

Your suggestion about the label font works perfectly, thanks! In the chart in section TEST2, in the "scam" bar, the word "scam" is written to the left of the bar ("symbolic y coord"). I would like to (1) replace that text with the text "(scam) example.com" and (2) move all the bars to the right so the symbolic y coords do not overprint the bars. So, instead of saying \addplot coordinates {(4943,maldom)}, I would like to say \addplot coordinates {(4943,\barchartdomain{maldom}{example.com/maldom})}. Is there a way?

You can add yticklabels to the plot definition. These can contain any text or macros, and will automatically allocate space.
It is important to put the labels after the definition of the symbolic coords, otherwise these will overwrite the label specification. The order should be the same as in the \addplot command.
Using yticklabels you no longer need the three extra \node lines.
Code, also incorporating the font setting in nodes near coordsstyle:
\subsection{TEST2}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    % title  = \textbf{Brauchen wir einen Titel?},
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={\,},
    y=4.5mm,
    xbar,
    xmin=-2,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    yticklabel style  = {font=\scshape},
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = {0.05, lower},
    ytick             = data,
    bar width         = 3mm,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scshape, /pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},
%
    % hier absteigend nach Häufigkeit(!) sortieren
    symbolic y coords = {
      maldom,
      malware,
      scam,
    },
    yticklabels       = {\barchartdomain{maldom}{example.com/maldom},\barchartdomain{scam}{example.com},\barchartdomain{malware}{example.com/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/malware}},
    ]
%
    % hier ist die Sortierung egal
    \addplot coordinates {
      (4943,maldom)
      (56,scam)
      (545,malware)
    }; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \caption{}
\end{figure}

Result:


This works beautifully! Thanks a lot!
