# Set pgfplots font to that of article

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, math-fonts

I have a document with a custom font `montserrat`. I also have the following plot:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[extralight,defaultfam,light,tabular,lining]{montserrat} % Font

% For bar chart
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymajorgrids=true,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels={Foo,Bar,Baz,FooBar,FooBaz},
        every axis plot/.append style={
            ybar,
            bar width=20,
            bar shift=0pt,
            fill
        },
        ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot[purple] coordinates {(1,1)};
        \addplot[red] coordinates {(2,2)};
        \addplot[yellow] coordinates {(3,3)};
        \addplot[gray] coordinates {(4,6)};
        \addplot[blue] coordinates {(5,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, only the x axis seems to adapt to the montserrat font, i.e., the y axis still has the default latex font. How can I get the y axis to be displayed in the `montserrat` font as well?

[image: Text]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this font, but does it come with a math font?

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185930/47927

Comment: Try `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}` after `\usepackage[...]{montserrat}`.

Comment: That worked Henri, thanks! Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Henri Menke user.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[extralight,defaultfam,light,tabular,lining]{montserrat} % Font
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
% For bar chart
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymajorgrids=true,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels={Foo,Bar,Baz,FooBar,FooBaz},
        every axis plot/.append style={
            ybar,
            bar width=20,
            bar shift=0pt,
            fill
        },
        ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot[purple] coordinates {(1,1)};
        \addplot[red] coordinates {(2,2)};
        \addplot[yellow] coordinates {(3,3)};
        \addplot[gray] coordinates {(4,6)};
        \addplot[blue] coordinates {(5,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tell `pgfplots` that the tick labels should be text in `\normalfont`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,border=2]{standalone}

\usepackage[extralight,defaultfam,light,tabular,lining]{montserrat} % Font

% For bar chart
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymajorgrids=true,
        scale only axis,
        tick label style={font=\normalfont},
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels={Foo,Bar,Baz,FooBar,FooBaz},
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
        yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
        every axis plot/.append style={
            ybar,
            bar width=20,
            bar shift=0pt,
            fill
        },
        ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot[purple] coordinates {(1,1)};
        \addplot[red] coordinates {(2,2)};
        \addplot[yellow] coordinates {(3,3)};
        \addplot[gray] coordinates {(4,6)};
        \addplot[blue] coordinates {(5,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]