# How to color the background of a table?

Tags: tables, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color entire table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63883/color-entire-table)

How can I color the background of a *tabular* environment?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\hfill\begin{tabular}{|lp{10cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\hline
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Check this related [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1407/15717)

Comment: I think you will find the answer in [Color entire table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63883/color-entire-table?rq=1). If not, please, explain it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Xcolor

Try `xcolor` You can even set alternating colors

```
\documentclass[table]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{
 \begin{tabular}{|lp{10cm}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Test}}\\
  \hline
   Test: & Test\\
   Test: & Test\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
 }

\rowcolors*{1}{red}{red}
\begin{tabular}{|lp{10cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\hline
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Just for my sake i'd like to say that typographically spoken vertical rules are odd. Avoid them. And i stripped `\mbox{}..`  cause i can't see the purpose. )

### Tabu

The `tabu` Package provides you with some more convenient commands

```
\documentclass[table]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}




\taburowcolors [1] 7 {green .. brown}

\begin{tabu}{|lp{10cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\hline
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
Test: & Test\\
\hline
\end{tabu}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error: "LaTeX Error: File `colortbl.sty' not found."

Comment: Ok, I guess the [table] option belongs to xcolor.