# Patch tabular environment with colorbox

Tags: tables, environments, etoolbox

I'm trying to quickly add a colored background using `colorbox` to all tables as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63883/color-entire-table).  While I could just update all the TeX by hand, I am trying to patch the `tabular` environment to keep the TeX content as "clean" as possible (and there are 200+ tables to update).

I've tried two different methods, but they are giving me the same error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\color@b@x ...hbox {\kern \fboxsep {\set@color #3}
                                                  \kern \fboxsep }\dimen@ \h...
l.22     \begin{tabular}
                        {ll}
```

TeX:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,letterpaper,openright]{scrbook}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
\usepackage{booktabs}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

% Method One:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
\usepackage{etoolbox}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\colorbox{gray}\begingroup}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\endgroup}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

% Method Two                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
%\usepackage{xpatch}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
%xpretocmd{\tabular}{\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{gray}\begingroup}{}{\patchfailed}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
%xapptocmd{\endtabular}{\endgroup\endgroup}{}{\patchfailed}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

\begin{table}[h]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    \caption{Test Table}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    \label{testtable}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    \begin{tabular}{ll}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        \toprule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        Test 1 & Test 2 \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        Test 3 & Test 4 \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        \bottomrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    \end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
\end{table}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` for delimiting an argument.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm still trying... clearly I am lost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would be careful to redefine the `tabular` environment altogether, as it may be used in different contexts than a table (for example to typeset the author name and address). Since probably the tables to which you want to add the background color are in `table` environments, we'll patch only those.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,letterpaper,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{xpatch,letltxmacro}
%% A storage bin
\newsavebox{\tabularbox}
%% We patch the tabular environments only inside table
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \LetLtxMacro\tabular\colortabular
  \LetLtxMacro\endtabular\endcolortabular
}
%% Start: save a copy of \tabular and \endtabular
\LetLtxMacro\colortabular\tabular
\LetLtxMacro\endcolortabular\endtabular
%% Patch the copies
\xpretocmd{\colortabular}
  {\setbox\tabularbox=\hbox\bgroup} % start building a box
  {}{}
\xapptocmd{\endcolortabular}
  {%
   \egroup % finish the box
   \begingroup
   \fboxsep=0pt % no padding
   \colorbox{black!30}{\box\tabularbox}% typeset the box on a background
   \endgroup
   }
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test Table}\label{testtable}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Test 1 & Test 2 \\
Test 3 & Test 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer explains a lot to me.  Wish I could +1k.

Comment: @JeffreyClark You can add a bounty to the question and retroactively award it to egreg.

Answer (score 3):

With a new environment `Tabular` with the same parameter settings

```
\documentclass[parskip=half*]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,varwidth}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\newsavebox\TBox   
\newenvironment{Tabular}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\TBox}\varwidth{\linewidth}\tabular}
  {\endtabular\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}%
   \fboxsep=1pt\colorbox{black!20}{\usebox\TBox}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{Tabular}{ll}\toprule
Test 1 & Test 2 \\
Test 3 & Test 4 \\\bottomrule
\end{Tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
Test 1 & Test 2 \\
Test 3 & Test 4 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]