# How to represent these forms of data in Latex?

Tags: tables

[image]

[image]

In first, the one with "process id", I thought this can be done with table but don't know how.

and in the second one, I thought of `equation` in this but could not figure out how can I place the data outside the Matrix and also there is no representation of equation on the left side of it

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please ask only one question. It would help to see add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. The compilable code, starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63887/124842  (first question), https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130799/124842 (secondquestion)

Comment: @Bobyandbob thanks for your help and suggestion, will keep them in mind next time....

Comment: @Ap00 Your question will probably be unanswered if you do not provide a MWE.

Comment: @BarisErkus Yeah okay but, my question was answered by the comment made by Bobyandbob. If it really matters I can provide MWE with it ...

Comment: No need, if those questions solved your problem we'll close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I perceive two main challenges with the first table:

- How to make it fit inside the textblock? A basic `tabular` environment gives no guarantee that this 17-column table will actually fit.
- How to typeset the header line ("Process ID...")?

To meet these challenges, I suggest you employ (a) a `tabular*` environment whose width is set to `\textwidth` and (b) a `\multicolumn` directive, as is done in the code below. Incidentally, I would right-align rather than left-align the numbers.

A third challenge could be how to render the entire tabular material with a light-gray background. In the code below, I've used the technique proposed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63897/5001) to address this challenge.

Regarding the second table, I'd say it's not right to set up the numeric material as a (mathematical) matrix surrounded by curly braces. What's far more important is to line up the header cells with their corresponding columns. Separately, I'd also say that it's important -- for the sake of legibility -- to align the numbers on their respective decimal markers. I would therefore use a `tabular` environment along with the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package for the four "real" data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.85} % define a suitable version of "light gray"
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out inter-column whitespace
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}   % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63897/5001
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{17}{r}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Process ID: 3939}\\[0.5ex]
105 & 104& 104& 106& 105& 104& 104& 106& 105& 104& 104& 106& 5& 4& 5& 5 &0 \\
40 & 41 & \dots \\
3  &  3 & \dots \\
3  & 12 & \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}}
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]} 
    c *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\toprule
\mytab{Distinct\\System Call} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Trace} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & {1}   & {2}   &       & {$m-1$} & {$m$}   \\
\midrule
1  & 0.051  & 0.055  & \dots  & 0.049 & 0.051 \\
2  & 0.122  & 0.125  & \dots  & \\
   &{\vdots}&{\vdots}&{\vdots}& \\
155& 0.101  & 0.1    & \dots  & \\
167& 0.03   & 0.03   & \dots  & 0.02  & 0.03  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and much-needed advice about data representation.... Actually, I was writing it in a 2 column IEEE journal format so the first table would not fit inside it...so should I just reduce this one's size...??

P.S - Never mind just chaged `\textwidth` to `\linewidth` and now it fits